# Which command was used to install grub?

Tags: grub

I need to re-install `grub` (to fix the boot-hole security issue).
I don't want to make a mistake, and because I'm not very comfortable with `grub`, I ask myself if there is a way to find the `grub-install` command which was used to install the current `grub` on the machine.

Thanks for your help.

Environment : Grub 2, Manjaro (Arch linux), EFI boot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `efibootmgr -v` as root.  The first line will be `BootCurrent: NNNN` where NNNN is a hexadecimal four-digit number.

Find the corresponding "BootNNNN" line. It will look similar to this:

```
BootNNNN* Manjaro        HD(X,GPT,11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555,0x800,0x82000)/File(\...\something.efi)
```

- `NNNN` is the number from the first line,
- `Manjaro` is the human-readable boot item description string (can be anything),
- `X` is the number of the disk in the order detected by the UEFI firmware,
- `11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555` is the PARTUUID of the EFI System Partition the bootloader is installed into,
- and `\...\something.efi` is a Windows-style path name on the EFI System Partition, identifying the bootloader file to use. With GRUB + Secure Boot, it is usually `shimx64.efi`, `shim.efi` or something similar, referring to the Secure Boot shim bootloader, which will then load the file named `grubx64.efi` in the same directory.

The EFI System Partition might be mounted as `/boot/efi`, or `/boot`, or not mounted at all; different distributions do things differently here. If it's mounted at `/boot/efi`, run `ls -l /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.efi` and compare the length of that file to the file at the bootloader path identified by `efibootmgr -v`: if they match, you'll know that you probably should update the fallback bootloader too. (Remember this - more about it later.)

Once you know the PARTUUID, you will be able to use `blkid` or `lsblk -o +PARTUUID` to identify the Linux device name corresponding to the EFI System Partition (ESP for short). Now you'll have all the pieces you need to reconstruct the `grub-install` command.

**However,** with Secure Boot, the first "bootloader" registered to the system NVRAM will actually be the Secure Boot shim, not GRUB. You don't want to change this fact.

So, you'll probably want to use the `--no-nvram` option to avoid changing your NVRAM boot variables. As a result, the command to re-install GRUB should be:

```
grub-install --no-nvram /dev/<the disk device corresponding to your ESP partition>
```

If GRUB is currently also installed into the fallback bootloader path `\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.efi` on the ESP, you'll want to add the `--force-extra-removable` option to the `grub-install` command, so it will update that too.

Note that if you are using the Secure Boot shim bootloader, it will be important to update the shim on the ESP too. Before rebooting the system, verify that both the GRUB and the shim on the ESP have recent enough timestamps. Anything after 2020-07-28 should be good. If the shim package won't update the shim file on the ESP automatically, you can just find the updated shim wherever the package installation procedure puts it, and copy it over the old shim on the ESP.

With Secure Boot and GRUB, the typical layout of the ESP would be like this:

- `<ESP mountpoint>/EFI/<name of distro>/grubx64.efi` = the actual GRUB
- `<ESP mountpoint>/EFI/<name of distro>/shimx64.efi` = the Secure Boot shim
- `<ESP mountpoint>/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.efi` = the fallback boot copy of the shim
- `<ESP mountpoint>/EFI/BOOT/grubx64.efi` = the fallback boot copy of GRUB

The paths with the `<name of distro>` component are generally supposed to be the primary bootloader, but the fallback copy will be useful if the system "forgets" the NVRAM settings for any reason, like with a UEFI firmware update that resets all the firmware settings (aka "BIOS settings") to factory defaults.

Comment: Thanks to your explanations, I pretty sure my system seems to not use Secure-boot (no shim... files). So I think I'm not concerned by the boot-hole problem. Thanks for your help !

Comment: If you had set your own Secure Boot keys, it might be possible that you had your GRUB signed with your own key... but that's enough of an effort that I think you would have remembered doing it. Just in case, `pesign -S -i filename.efi` shows the name of the certificate used in signing the `.efi` file, if the file is signed for Secure Boot.

Comment: `No signature found` ! thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to reinstall GRUB to fix this vulnerability. Simply updating the package should be enough. If GRUB is the only boot loader you might want to update your `/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/BOOTX64.EFI` - grub-install will not do that.

Also `grub-install` is meant for old-style MBR systems, it's not really needed any more on UEFI enabled devices.

To be extra sure please check the dates of your grub files in /boot/efi/EFI. Since I'm not sure where the files are installed, please run this command and post its output

```
find /boot \( -iname grubx64.efi -o -iname 'shim*.efi' \)  -exec ls -l '{}' \;
```

Comment: Good to know. I was worried about that because on the update notice, they mention to re-install grub to complete the fix. `Fixes Boot-Hole issue. You need to re-install grub on your system to complete the security fix` with a links to a their wiki.
https://forum.manjaro.org/t/stable-update-2020-08-16-kernels-plasma-kde-framework-systemd-pamac-virtualbox-firefox/1303

Comment: Here the result of the find command : `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 123904 30 déc.   2018 /boot/efi/EFI/Manjaro/grubx64.efi`

Comment: This file is very old. Are you sure you've actually updated? Perhaps you'll have to update it manually only I don't know where this file is installed in your filesystem. Please run the same command only use `/usr` instead of `/boot`. Maybe you'll have to ask the same question on Manjaro's own forums. I don't know how Arch packages get updated exactly. Also if the package has been updated but this file hasn't been - it might indicate a serious bug which needs to be resolved.

Comment: Nothing in /usr. the file date hasn't changed since i've installer this system

Comment: I presume the package is cached somewhere in /var but again I don't know the packaging format or how to extract a file from it.